# Apex Chart Customer tool tip doesn't work

Tags: apexcharts

I am trying to use the custom tooltip from Apex Charts, have tried multiple examples online but they dont seem to work.. I am getting a tool tip but it seems like its the standard tooltip.

```
const { _getSum } = require("../helper/dynamicFormat");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Validator } = require("../middlewares");
const resolvers = require("../resolvers");
const db = require("../models");
const moment = require("moment");
const _ = require("lodash");
const { getRandomColors } = require("../helper/colors");
 
router.get(
  "/",
  [Validator.check("query").not().isEmpty()],
  Validator,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { query } = req.query;
      const options = JSON.parse(query);
       
      let idleData=[
        {
          x: '3R4785',
          y: [
            new Date(1789, 3, 1,18,30).getTime(),
            new Date(1789, 3, 1,19,30).getTime(),
           
          ]},{
            x: '3R4785',
            y: [
              new Date(1789, 3, 1,21).getTime(),
              new Date(1789, 3, 1,22).getTime(),
             
            ]
          }

      ]

      let drivingData= [
        {
          x: '3R4785',
          y: [
            new Date(1789, 3, 1,22).getTime(),
            new Date(1789, 3, 1,23).getTime()
          ]
        },
      
      ]

     let parkingData=[
      {
        x: '3R4785',
        y: [
          new Date(1789, 3, 1, 23).getTime(),
          new Date(1789, 3, 1,24).getTime(),
           
        ]
      },
    
    ]

     
      res.render("millage", {
        options: JSON.stringify({
          series: [
            {
              name: 'Idle',
              data:idleData
            },
            
            {
              name: 'Driving',
              data:drivingData
            },
            {
              name: 'Parking',
              data: parkingData
            },
         
          ],
          chart: {
            height: 350,
            type: 'rangeBar'
          },
          plotOptions: {
            bar: {
              horizontal: true,
              barHeight: '50%',
              rangeBarGroupRows: true
            }
          },
          colors: [
            "#008FFB", "#00E396", "#FEB019", "#FF4560", "#775DD0",
            "#3F51B5", "#546E7A", "#D4526E", "#8D5B4C", "#F86624",
            "#D7263D", "#1B998B", "#2E294E", "#F46036", "#E2C044"
          ],
          fill: {
            type: 'solid'
          },
          xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            format: 'hh mm'
          },
          tooltip: {
            custom:  function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
              var data = w.globals.initialSeries[seriesIndex].data[dataPointIndex];
              console.log("tooltip",series,seriesIndex,dataPointIndex,w)
              return '<ul>' +
              '<li><b>Price</b>: ' + data.x + '</li>' +
              '<li><b>Number</b>: ' + data.y + '</li>' +
        
              '</ul>';
            }
          },
          legend: {
            position: 'right'
          },
          
        }),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(" ~ file: millage.js ~ line 13 ~ error", error);
    }
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

I have tried multiple examples online, but nothing changes the standard tooltip.. I get a tooltip but it's not the one I want. Also when I try to console out the tooltip function, nothing comes..

I tried also made sure to use the latest apext charts

this is how I render the component:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@latest"></script>

</head>

<body>
  {{{body}}}

</body>

</html>
```

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
    const defaultOptions = {

    }

    const options = JSON.parse(`{{options}}`.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById("chart"), { ...defaultOptions, ...options });

    chart.render();
</script>
```

[image]